# How to map a Value Type which has a reference to an entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm having a problem with a mapping in Entity Framework.

I have the following classes (simplified):

```
public class Building
{

    public int ID { get; set; }     
    // *.. snip..* other properties
    public Location Location { get; private set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public Country country {get; set}
}
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Building and Country are entities, they are saved in the database. Location is a value type and should map to the same table as Building.

However, when I map it this way, entity framework wants to map Location to a table as well and is complaining it has no Key. I don't want to give it a key since it belongs to the Building and should not be an entity at all.

I have seen workarounds which say you need to put Country on the Building-class, but that just doesn't feel good (and is semantically just plain wrong).

I'm using Entity Framework 5

Comment: You're looking for [complex types](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know, the problem is that as soon as that complex type has a reference to an entity, EF wants to put the complex type in a table as well

Comment: What a nice question. Actually, I usually put focus on domain logic, and I don't care at all about how the ORM persists data (therefore I wouldn't see adding an Id column in Location as a big problem). If I really had to care about how data is stored, I'd consider not mixing domain objects with ORM entities, by creating a specific layer to persist (creating entities to attend ORM), though this might put more complexity in the archicteture. If you came to a conclusion, let us know, maybe CQRS solves this.

Comment: Yeah, in the end, I just got rid of EF. No ORM is much simpler :-)

Comment: You could use NHibernate instead of the EF. Here you can do that things.

Comment: I would highly recommend using Dapper.net.  It is super easy to use and setup and is extremely lightweight and fast.  Feel free to message me if you need some more info on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the release of [Entity Framework Core 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/), it is now possible to achieve this using [owned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities).

Your configuration would look like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Building>().OwnsOne(x => x.Location);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasOne(x => x.Country);
    // ...
}
```

This way, properties from `Location` class will be a part of the table `Building` class is mapped to. This means you will only have tables for `Building` and `Country` classes and the `Building` table will have a foreign key to the `Country` table.

I know it's been a long since you posted the question, but I thought this answer might be helpful to someone who comes across this question.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the Entity Framework shouldn't allow such a case.

I understand that you don't consider the Location as an Entity but adding entity references to complex types doesn't seem like a solid approach either. The relationship of a building to a country is quite straight forward. A building belongs to one country. Thus a building model should include a country id.  What would you expect to be mapped?

If you would expect the table Building to have just three columns `ID, Street, CountryId` and you still want to hold the Location model then you should use the following complex type.

```
public class Location
{
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public int countryId {get; set}
}
```

If however you would expect your Building table to have all the fields from the model Country then that could lead to some tricky situations like what would happen If you wanted to add new fields to the Country model or If you wanted to add other complex types or entities to your Country model according to a new Business Case.

Those cases would mess with the relational concept and would over-complicate your structure without any meaningful reason. (in my opinion of course)

Answer (score -3):

You may mark Location property in Building class with [NotMapped] Attribute.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Building
{
    [NotMapped]
    public Location Location { get; private set; }
}
```

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for. This wouldn't save the locations of entities which is what he wants to do.

Comment: Indeed, that doesn't solve it. I want Location inside the Building-table with a reference to the countries-table. I need it mapped

Comment: In that case, I think you will have to map 'location' to a table which relates Building and country tables.

Comment: Hm, I wanted to avoid that. My database structure shouldn't be dependend on my domain model. The location data just belongs to the Building, it shouldn't be in a separate table.